# TDM-GCC 5.1.0 で c99 オプションを指定したコンパイル時、printf の %lf で出力される結果が想定と異なる

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, c99

TDM-GCC 5.1.0 で以下のソースを `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic test.c` のように `c99` を指定してコンパイルを実行すると、`%lf` 指定した方の出力が `0.000000` になってしまいます。

**対象のソースコード:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double v = 3.1415926;
    printf("%f\n", v);
    printf("%lf\n", v);
}
```

**実行結果 (c99 オプションありでコンパイル):**

```
3.141593
0.000000
```

一方、オプション指定なし(`gcc test.c`)でコンパイルした場合には、期待通りの結果が得られます。

**実行結果 (c99 オプションなしでコンパイル):**

```
3.141593
3.141593
```

[image: screen shot]

`printf` での `%lf` の使用は C99 では適合なはずなので、おかしな結果です。

以前使用していた古いバージョンの GCC (MinGw gcc3.2) では`c99`オプション使用時に`%lf`は使用できていたので、この GCC での固有バグではないかと思いますが、当面（バグフィックスされるまで）困るので回避方法を探しています。

`C99` オプションなしでコンパイルした場合は問題ないので、なんらかの方法で回避できるのではないかと思っています。

Comment: 例えば`gcc -std=gnu99 -pedantic  test.c` だとＯＫですが、これってC99 pedanticと同じ意味ですかね？

Comment: 同じGCC 5.1.0で引数も`gcc -std=c99 -pedantic test.c`であっても[Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FwhR0B0HWoEN8QXX)では正しく動作しました。TDM-GCC固有の問題かもしれません。「回避方法」とはどのようなものを想定されていますか？ （どこまで変更可能で、どこは変更せずに済ませたいですか？）

Comment: コメントでの例のように別のオプションを追加指定するか通常のシステムヘッダの利用に先立ちなんらかのマクロを指定する（あるいは-Dオプションでマクロ指定)。includeヘッダなどを直接修正するというのは最終手段。gcc（コンパイラ関連）自体のソースは修正しない。 というような考えです。

Comment: ご指摘のように`%lf`はISO C99準拠であれば使えるはずですが、[GCCのC99準拠状況リスト](https://gcc.gnu.org/c99status.html)を見ると、`%lf`への対応はライブラリの仕事であってコンパイラがすべきことは無い、と言っています。今手元にTDM-GCC環境が無いので試せないのですが、もしかしたらライブラリのバージョンも関係してくるかもしれないです。

Comment: 関係があるのかどうかは不明ですが参考までに [c - printf and long double](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089174/printf-and-long-double) MinGW ではなく Windows の msvcrt.dll 内の printf が使われてしまっているのではないかと。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  C99 指定かどうかで使用するライブラリが変わるということですか？

Comment: 関連?: ["MinGW doesn't produce warnings"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363795/mingw-doesnt-produce-warnings) -- Stack Overflow

Comment: @metropolis 私もそれを考えて`cl test.c` は試してみたんですが`%lf`は機能しているようでした。この場合`double`のサイズも同じだと思われるのでおそらく関係ないかと思うんですが、gccからのmsvcライブラリの呼び出し時に未対応だとgccがみなしているというのはあるかもしれません。

Comment: @nekketsuuu 同じ症状ですね。

Comment: 蛇足ですが、直接質問にはそうと書いていなくてもＣ９９での動作をさせたいというのは理解していただけると思います。また、別の問題が生じて欲しいとも思わないことは別に言うまでもないことだと信じています。（一般には解決の方法にデメリットを加味しなければならないと思いますが、ある部分をＣ９９の動作をさせることで他の部分でＣ９９の動作をしていたのがしなくなるというのは望む動作ではありません）

Answer (score 9):

## `-std=c99`と`-std=gnu99`で動作が変わる理由

TDM-GCCがベースにしているMinGWにはMinGW stdioとMSVCRT stdioの２種類のstdioが存在します。`__mingw_printf()`と`__msvcrt_printf()`の名前でアクセスできます。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    double v = 3.1415926;
    printf("%f\n", v);
    printf("printf(): %lf\n", v);
    __mingw_printf("__mingw_printf(): %lf\n", v);
    __msvcrt_printf("__msvcrt_printf(): %lf\n", v);
}
```

MSVCRT stdioの実体は`MSVCRT.dll`ですがこれは1998年にリリースされたVisual C++ 6.0のものですので、C99やC11といった仕様とは無縁です。[Format Specification Fields: printf and wprintf Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa246400(v=vs.60).aspx)に`printf()`のドキュメントがありましたが、[`%zu`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa272936(v=vs.60).aspx)という指定も存在しません。

さてMinGW stdioとMSVCRT stdioは`<stdio.h>`の次の記述により`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`の値により動作が切り替わります。

```
#if __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
/*
 * User has expressed a preference for C99 conformance...
 */
（略）

__mingw_stdio_redirect__
int printf (const char *__format, ...)
{
  register int __retval;
  __builtin_va_list __local_argv; __builtin_va_start( __local_argv, __format );
  __retval = __mingw_vprintf( __format, __local_argv );
  __builtin_va_end( __local_argv );
  return __retval;
}

（略）

#else
/*
 * Default configuration: simply direct all calls to MSVCRT...
 */
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW fprintf (FILE*, const char*, ...);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW printf (const char*, ...);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW sprintf (char*, const char*, ...);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW vfprintf (FILE*, const char*, __VALIST);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW vprintf (const char*, __VALIST);
_CRTIMP int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW vsprintf (char*, const char*, __VALIST);

#endif
```

ここで`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`は`<_mingw.h>`で設定されています。

```
/* Activation of MinGW specific extended features:
 */
#ifndef __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO
/*
 * If user didn't specify it explicitly...
 */
# if   defined __STRICT_ANSI__  ||  defined _ISOC99_SOURCE \
   ||  defined _POSIX_SOURCE    ||  defined _POSIX_C_SOURCE \
   ||  defined _XOPEN_SOURCE    ||  defined _XOPEN_SOURCE_EXTENDED \
   ||  defined _GNU_SOURCE      ||  defined _BSD_SOURCE \
   ||  defined _SVID_SOURCE
   /*
    * but where any of these source code qualifiers are specified,
    * then assume ANSI I/O standards are preferred over Microsoft's...
    */
#  define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO    1
# else
   /*
    * otherwise use whatever __MINGW_FEATURES__ specifies...
    */
#  define __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO    (__MINGW_FEATURES__ & __MINGW_ANSI_STDIO__)
# endif
#endif
```

コンパイルオプション`-std=c99`や`-ansi`を付けると`__STRICT_ANSI__`が定義されることに連動して`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`も定義されます。
その結果、MinGW stdioとMSVCRT stdioとが切り替わります。

## 回避策

原理がわかれば明快です。

- `-std=gnu99`を指定する（`-std=c99`や`-ansi`を指定しない）
- `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0`を指定する
- `printf()`ではなく`__msvcrt_printf()`を使用する

ぐらいでしょうか。

## `-std=c99`で使われるMinGW stdioが`%lf`を正しく扱えない原因

TDM-GCCのソースコード`mingwrt-3.21-mingw32-src.tar.xz`を確認しました。`printf()`は最終的に`mingwex/stdio/pformat.c`で定義されている`__pformat()`に辿り着きます。

```
      case 'l':
        /*
         * Interpret the argument as explicitly of a
         * `long' or `long long' data type.
         */
        if( *fmt == 'l' )
        {
          /* Modifier is `ll'; data type is `long long' sized...
           * Skip the second `l', and set length accordingly.
           */
          ++fmt;
          length = PFORMAT_LENGTH_LLONG;
        }

        else
          /* Modifier is `l'; data type is `long' sized...
           */
          length = PFORMAT_LENGTH_LONG;

#           ifndef _WIN32
          /*
           * Microsoft's MSVCRT implementation also uses `l'
           * as a modifier for `long double'; if we don't want
           * to support that, we end this case here...
           */
          state = PFORMAT_END;
          break;

          /* otherwise, we simply fall through...
           */
#       endif

      case 'L':
        /*
         * Identify the appropriate argument as a `long double',
         * when associated with `%a', `%A', `%e', `%E', `%f', `%F',
         * `%g' or `%G' format specifications.
         */
        stream.flags |= PFORMAT_LDOUBLE;
        state = PFORMAT_END;
        break;
```

となっていて、`_WIN32`が定義されていない環境ではC99相当の`l`フラグを無視しますが、`_WIN32`が定義されている環境ではMSVCRTと動作を合わせるために`L`フラグへfall throughすることで`long double`と見なすようになっています。

なお、MSVCRTについてですが、歴史的に16bit時代は`float` 32bit、`double` 64bit、`long double` 80bitとしていました。そのため`long double`を`printf()`する際に`%lf`を使用していました。Windows 95・32bit化の際これを改め`long double` 64bitと変更しました。その結果、`printf()`の`%lf`が`long double`を表していても`double`を表していてもどの道64bitであり影響がなく`printf()`の使い方としては曖昧になってしまいました。
しかし **MinGWでは`long double`を独自に96bitとしてしまっています（本来はVisual C++に合わせて64bitとすべきところ）。これは仕様バグとしか言いようがありません。** しかも前述のように`printf()`は16bit時代のVisual C++の動作を引きずって`%lf`を`long double`とみなしてしまっています。

この食い違いに対処するには`printf("%lf\n", (long double)v);`等、明示的なキャストを行い正しく引数を与える必要があります。

別の根本的な解決方法としてはgccのコンパイルオプション`-mlong-double-64`を使うことです。しかし、これを実現するには`printf()`を含むランタイムすべてをビルドし直す必要があります。というかgccからビルドし直す方が早いでしょうか。

## `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`マクロについて

`<_mingw.h>`には次のコメントがあります。

```
/* These are defined by the user (or the compiler)
   to specify how identifiers are imported from a DLL.

   __DECLSPEC_SUPPORTED            Defined if dllimport attribute is supported.
   __MINGW_IMPORT                  The attribute definition to specify imported
                                   variables/functions.
   _CRTIMP                         As above.  For MS compatibility.
   __MINGW32_VERSION               Runtime version.
   __MINGW32_MAJOR_VERSION         Runtime major version.
   __MINGW32_MINOR_VERSION         Runtime minor version.
   __MINGW32_BUILD_DATE            Runtime build date.

   Macros to enable MinGW features which deviate from standard MSVC
   compatible behaviour; these may be specified directly in user code,
   activated implicitly, (e.g. by specifying _POSIX_C_SOURCE or such),
   or by inclusion in __MINGW_FEATURES__:

   __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO          Select a more ANSI C99 compatible
                                   implementation of printf() and friends.
```

*These are defined by the user*とか*these may be specified directly in user code*とありますから、指定しても構わないと思います。
そもそも、MinGW stdioとMSVCRT stdioとの切り替え選択という内部実装に強く依存した行為ですから、指定するには細心の注意を払うべきですし、注意して行うのであればためらう必要はないかと。

> たとえば、先の‌​メールで指摘されているように`_POSIX‌​_C_SOURCE`、`_XOPEN_SOURCE` (または`_GNU_SOURCE`) を使うとどうなるのでしょうか？

これに関しては本回答及びコードをよく確認してください。`#if __USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`を不成立させたいのですから、いずれを`#define`しても期待する結果は得られません。

Comment: `-D__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO=0`を指定した場合(`-std=gnu99`を指定した場合も)今度は`%zu` が使用できなくなります。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さん、[ここ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34013/printf-%E3%81%AE-lf-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/34023?noredirect=1#comment33581_34013)で確認しましたがそのような条件は挙げられていませんでした。質問文を訂正してください。

Comment: もちろんそう(`%zu`については書いていなかった（書いた時には気づいてなかった）)なんですが、`-std=c99`のオプションを指定する（したい）理由は要するにＣ９９での（コーディングとそのコンパイル（コンパイラによるチェック）もろもろの）実行動作だというのは理解していただけますよね。

Comment: 提示していた問題は解決するがそのために新たな問題が生じるという場合、そういう条件は書かれていなかったと言われて質問を訂正するような必要があるんでしょうか？

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さん、[snprintf の返値について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/4236)でもコメントしましたが、規格・仕様と実装は別問題です。特にMSVCRTはMS-DOS時代から30年以上の歴史・互換性を維持していますから、仕様通りには動作しない部分もあります。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY さん、第三者の視点では質問文に対する回答として成立しており、質問文にない`%zu`が議論されないのは当然です。状況を整理して新たに質問をされてはどうでしょうか？

Comment: この場合仕様通りに動作させようとするフラグが`-std=c99`の指定であって、私的にはバグだと認識しています。

Comment: 私も回答としては成立していると思います。だから「`%zu`についての対処が書かれていない」と非難しているわけではありません。指摘しただけです。ただ、結果生じる新たな問題にたいしては、回答になくても指摘以降議論はあってよいと思います。

Comment: @sayuri 他の回答でも同じリンクをはりましたが、MinGWのメーリスに「`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`はすぐにでも内部で予約されたマクロになる可能性があるから使わずに他のマクロを使うべきだ」と主張しているメールが[あった](http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/snprintf-and-USE-MINGW-ANSI-STDIO-td35399.html)のですが、Windows環境で`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`に変わるようなマクロは存在しているのでしょうか？　たとえば、先のメールで指摘されているように`_POSIX_C_SOURCE`、 `_XOPEN_SOURCE` (または `_GNU_SOURCE`) を使うとどうなるのでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu さん、コメントには書ききれない内容でしたので、回答に加筆しました。ご確認ください。

Comment: @sayuri ああ、`_mingw.h`で`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`を定義するところに`_POSIX_C_SOURCE`などもいたのですね。気づいていませんでした。丁寧にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

[質問者さんのコメントの記述](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34013/printf-%E3%81%AE-lf-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/34028#comment33610_34013)より

> （TDM-GCCを）Ｃ９９での動作をさせたい

とのことですが、[snprintf の返値について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/4236)でもコメントしましたが、規格・仕様と実装は別問題です。GCCはコンパイラーの責任範囲にてC99に準拠しているのかもしれませんが、TDM-GCCが実行環境に利用しているMinGWやVisual C++ 6.0はC99準拠を謳っていないはずです。総じてTDM-GCCはC99に準拠していません。

C99を使用したいのであれば、C99に準拠した環境を選択すべきです。

Answer (score 0):

[@nekketsuuu さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34013/printf-%E3%81%AE-lf-%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6/34023?noredirect=1#comment33587_34013)の[リンク先の回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363795/mingw-doesnt-produce-warnings)で指摘されているように、どうやらTDM での元になっているMinGW4.8からのバグ(`%lf`が`long double`への指定だと解釈される)のようです。

```
printf("%lf\n", (long double)v);
```

とすると期待する値が表示されました。（つまり`long double`への指定だと解釈されていた）
(本来`long double`を意味する`%Lf`は期待通り動作します）

別の場所で`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO` マクロを指定するというような情報もあったのですが、
少なくとも現状は機能しないようです。
([sayuriさんの回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/34023/19110)から、機能しないというより`-std=c99`の場合既に指定された状態）

MinGW-w64ではこのような問題はないらしいのでコンパイラを切り替えるか

`-std=c99` の代わりに `-std=gnu99`を使用するのが簡易な解決のようです。
（しかし、その場合`%zu`が使用できなくなる）

`-std=c99` のような(`-std=c11` でも）標準規格指定がされた時に参照ヘッダが切り替わることが動作が異なる理由らしいですが、
そこら辺の切り替えをユーザーから問題を起こすことなしにうまく切り替えることができたらいいんですが、多分色々絡み合ってて難しいんでしょうね。

---

- 関連しそうなリンク (コメント参照)

  - mingw.orgにあるwiki上の[C99についてのページ](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/c99)。ここにMSVCRTとMinGWのC99についての歴‌​史が短く書いてあります。
  - MinGWのバグトラッカーにあった「`%lf`の表示がおかしい」というissueに対して、「ISO-C99では`printf(‌​)`の "l" は単に無視されるので無駄だ。また、Microsoftは`%lf`は`%Lf` (double long) になると言っている。`%f`を使おう」というコメントがついているところ: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2253/
  - Microsoftでの[サイズ指定解釈](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx)
  - `__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`を使ったら？と言っている[Stack Overflowでの回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296058/cant-print-correctly-a-long-double-in-c)

Comment: 関連(`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIOO`を使ったら？と言っているStack Overflowの回答です): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296058/cant-print-correctly-a-long-double-in-c

Comment: 関連(MinGWのバグトラッカーにあった`%lf`の表示がおかしいというissueに対して「ISO-C99では`printf()`の "l" は単に無視されるので無駄だ。また、Microsoftは`%lf`は`%Lf` (double long) になると言っている。`%f`を使おう」というコメントがついているところです): https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/2253/

Comment: 実際、ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 WG14/N1124の "7.19.6.1 The `fprintf` function" にある `l` の説明には、「`f`につくときには何の影響もない」と書かれています。Microsoftの解釈についてはまだ出典を見つけられていません。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  Microsoftでの[サイズ指定解釈](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/tcxf1dw6.aspx)

Comment: 自分でプログラムを書く分にはこれらのことを念頭に置いておけばいいけど、他の人のソースをコンパイルする場合が面倒ですね。(文字列の中なのでプリプロセッサで置き換えもできないし）

Comment: MinGWのメーリスに、`__USE_MINGW_ANSI_STDIO`は普通のユーザーが設定するべきではないと書かれたメールがありました。 http://mingw.5.n7.nabble.com/snprintf-and-USE-MINGW-ANSI-STDIO-td35399.html

Comment: mingw.orgにあるwikiにC99についてのページがありました。ここにMSVCRTとMinGWのC99についての歴史が短く書いてあります。 http://www.mingw.org/wiki/c99

Comment: @nekketsuuu  度々の情報提供ありがとうございます。m(_ _)m

Answer (score 0):

`-std=c99`指定の時は、`"%Lf"`と同じ扱いをされてしまっているのかな？
`printf()`は可変長引数で`float`は`double`に拡張されるため、昔は`"%lf"`は間違いでした。
[C99で`"%lf"`が許されるようになった](http://seclan.dll.jp/c99d/c99d0a2.htm#appendix_printf)とはいえ、敢えて`"%lf"`にしなくても良いのではないでしょうか。

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    double v = 3.1415926;
    printf("sizeof(double)      = %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(double));
    printf("sizeof(long double) = %u\n", (unsigned)sizeof(long double));
    printf("%%f  - double       :%f\n", v);
    printf("%%lf - double       :%lf\n", v);
    printf("%%Lf - double       :%Lf\n", v);
    printf("%%f  - (long double):%f\n", (long double)v);
    printf("%%lf - (long double):%lf\n", (long double)v);
    printf("%%Lf - (long double):%Lf\n", (long double)v);
}
```

コンパイル結果：

```
d:\tmp>gcc -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 double.c
```

実行結果：

```
d:\tmp>a.exe
sizeof(double)      = 8
sizeof(long double) = 12
%f  - double       :3.141593
%lf - double       :0.000000
%Lf - double       :0.000000
%f  - (long double):-88793646155857547477275137080339417618448384.000000
%lf - (long double):3.141593
%Lf - (long double):3.141593
```

コンパイル結果：

```
d:\tmp>gcc -Wall -pedantic double.c
double.c: In function 'main':
double.c:10:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%%Lf - double       :%Lf\n", v);
            ^
double.c:10:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
double.c:11:12: warning: format '%f' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'long double' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%%f  - (long double):%f\n", (long double)v);
            ^
double.c:12:12: warning: format '%lf' expects argument of type 'double', but argument 2 has type 'long double' [-Wformat=]
     printf("%%lf - (long double):%lf\n", (long double)v);
            ^
double.c:13:12: warning: unknown conversion type character 'L' in format [-Wformat=]
     printf("%%Lf - (long double):%Lf\n", (long double)v);
            ^
double.c:13:12: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
```

実行結果：

```
d:\tmp>a.exe
sizeof(double)      = 8
sizeof(long double) = 12
%f  - double       :3.141593
%lf - double       :3.141593
%Lf - double       :3.141593
%f  - (long double):-88793646155857547000000000000000000000000000.000000
%lf - (long double):-88793646155857547000000000000000000000000000.000000
%Lf - (long double):-88793646155857547000000000000000000000000000.000000
```

参考：

- [プログラミング言語 C の新機能 - A.2.5 長さ修飾子](http://seclan.dll.jp/c99d/c99d0a2.htm#appendix_printf)