# c++で大きな値をコンソール入力したときに、うまく読み込めません

Tags: c++, windows

お世話になります。

1≤A≤B≤10^18,1≤C,D≤10^9
であるときにコンソール上から数値を入力しようとしたのですが、
うまく各変数に入っていないようです。小さな値なら入るのですが、
大きくなると入りません。どのようにすれば、大きな値も入るでしょうか。
以下が書いたコードです。windows上で実行しております。
よろしくお願いいたします。

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    long A,B,C,D;

    cin >> A >> B >> C >> D;

    printf("%ld,%ld,%ld,%ld",A,B,C,D);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

前提としてC++言語の[整数型](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#.E6.80.A7.E8.B3.AA)はサイズが既定されていません。表にあるように`long`は「少なくとも32ビット幅」であり、これで表現できるのは-2,147,483,648から2,147,483,647までです。
また`long long`であれば「少なくとも64ビット幅」となるため、-9,223,372,036,854,775,808から9,223,372,036,854,775,807まで表現できるようになります。

別の方法として`<cstdint>`で提供される[固定幅の整数型](https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer)で`int64_t`を使用すれば明確に64ビット幅を得られます。

なお、[Windows環境における`long`は4バイト幅](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/data-type-ranges?view=vs-2019)と定められています。（日本語ページは機械翻訳によって誤った場所にも`long`が出現しているので注意）

---

champonさん、peridotiteさん共に誤解されているようですが、Windowsが32bit / 64bit、MinGWが32bit / 64bitかどうかに関わらず、Windows環境においては `long` は4バイト幅と定められています。
API呼び出しや`printf`のフォーマットなどに支障が出るため、基本的にはプラットフォーム（この場合はMicrosoft社）が定めたサイズに従っています。（と言いつつ、MinGWは`long double`のサイズを間違えているため、しばしば[問題](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/34023/4236)になっています。）

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。mingwの３２ビット版であったため、ダメだったようです。long longで表現できました。

Comment: 遅くなりましたが，ご指摘ありがとうございます．授業で聞いたことをそのままアウトプットしたのですが，改めて調べてみたところsayuriさんの通りWindws全体でlong型は32bit範囲までしか扱えないみたいですね．勉強になりました．ちゃんと自分で調べるようにします．．．m(_ _)m

Answer (score 1):

お使いのpcは何bitですか？
Linuxだとlong型は10^18まで格納できますが、windowsだと32bit版の場合はlongの範囲は-2147483648 〜 2147483647となります。
詳しいことをは調べてみてください。
解決策として、long long型を使えばできると思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。ご指摘により調べましたら、３２ビット版のmingwでありました。long longで解決いたしました。