# 未初期化変数を使用する部分を含む式は全体として動作未定義か？

Tags: c

例えば、以下のようなコードがあったとします。

```
int n;
int ret_scanf;
do {
    ret_scanf = scanf("%d", &n);
    if(ret_scanf != 1)//不正な文字があって入力に失敗した
        while(getchar()!='\n');//残っている入力を消費する
} while(n < 0 || ret_scanf != 1);//負の値か不正入力があった場合繰り返す
```

コードの目的は`int`の値を入力させて不正な入力や負の値が入力されたら再入力させるというものです。
（単なる例です、ＥＯＦの場合を考慮してないとかは無しで）

不正入力があって、`n`に値が設定されなかった場合
`n < 0 || ret_scanf != 1` での `n < 0` の部分は`n`が未初期化なので動作未定義です。

動作未定義の場合の１つ

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate

でも入力が不正だった場合`ret_scanf` が`0`になり、
`ret_scanf != 1`の部分が真になるので、
`n < 0` の部分で`n`の値がどのような値になっていて、
つまりこの部分の式の結果が真であろうと偽であろうと全体としては真になるものと思います。

つまり質問としては、
（通常動作未定義の部分を含むような式は全体においても動作未定義だと思われるが）
例のような場合、
全体としての式はやはり動作未定義ですか？
それとも動作未定義ではないのでしょうか？

（`ret_scanf != 1 || n < 0` とするべきとかは無しでね、例としてあげてるだけなので）

Comment: 便乗ですが、私からも質問させていただきます。`n`は未初期化なので動作未定義なのは分かりますが、`scanf`に`n`のポインタを渡している時点で、`n`の中身は未初期化ながらも、値を格納するための領域は確保されていると考えられますが、それでも尚、動作未定義なのでしょうか。本当に未使用ならコンパイルエラーでいいと思いますが、`n`のポインタが確定している以上、中の値は未初期化でも、領域は確保されているはず、という解釈はできないのでしょうか？

Comment: @soramimi  領域は確保されていますね。論点は何ですか？

Comment: 全くの未使用なら `n < 0` はコンパイルエラーまたは未定義動作なのは了解です。`n`の中身が未初期化でも、領域が確保されているのであれば、 `n < 0` は実行可能なのではないか、というところです。

Comment: @soramimi  私の理解している所では、実行可能であってもいいし、実行不能でもいいということになりますね。 要は、「値が決定していない自動変数を使用することが動作未定義である」からということになると思います。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

要点をはっきりさせるためのまとめ

[c11ドラフト](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)から引用

> 3.4.3
>
> 1. **undefined behavior**
>      behavior, upon use of a nonportable or erroneous program construct or of erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements
> 2. NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

「移植性のないまたは誤ったプログラム構成の使用時または誤ったデータの使用時に、
この国際規格は要求を課さない」

つまり、「未定義動作のプログラムの使用による結果は規定されない。」ということであって、
プログラマが期待するような実行をしてもいいし、
該当部分を削除してしまってもいい（プログラマが期待しないような実行をしてもよい）し、
「未初期化な変数を使用している」とメッセージを表示してコンパイルを止めてもよい。
等々。

> 「例のような場合、 全体としての式はやはり動作未定義ですか？ それとも動作未定義ではないのでしょうか？」

に対しての回答は、「動作未定義である」ということになります。

プログラムの実際の動作として、
それが部分的なものにできるかできないか（言い換えればプログラマの期待通りに動作するかしないか）というのも
結局のところ、コンパイラやその環境による（あるコンパイラでは期待するようなコードを出力し期待するように動作するかもしれないが、別のコンパイラではそうではないかもしれない）ので、
**それが、プログラマの期待するように動作すると期待してはいけない**。

Answer (score 2):

動作未定義です。

> 動作未定義の変数が例えどんな値であっても質問での式の値は真になると思いますが、この場合の式の一部分の動作未定義が全体に波‌​及する理由または根拠はなんですか？

[Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4105123/4315484)から引用します。これ自体もC++規格からの引用だそうです。

> Permissible undefined behavior ranges from **ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results**, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to **terminating a translation** or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

このように言語仕様はコンパイルエラーも認めています。「もしある実装がコンパイルエラーが発生しなかったとしたらどのような結果になるか？」と仮定した時点で言語仕様から離れて具体的な実装についての議論となります。

BLUEPIXYさんは言語仕様についての議論と具体的実装についての議論の混同が多々見られます（[その１](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/31646/4236)、[その２](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/34013/4236)）。まずはBLUEPIXYさん自身が言語仕様について知りたいのか具体的実装について知りたいのかをしっかりと自覚してください。

その上で、問題個所を完全に無視することも認められています。つまり`n < 0`がTRUE / FALSEどちらかを返すことすら保証されておらず、コンパイル時警告無しに`do-while`ループを削除することもあり得ます。

---

[Undefined behavior can result in time travel (among other things, but time travel is the funkiest)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633/)
[未定義動作はタイムトラベルを引き起こす（他にもいろいろあるけど、タイムトラベルが一番ぶっ飛んでる）](https://cpplover.blogspot.jp/2014/06/old-new-thing.html)

が参考になるかもしれません。例えば

> When undefined behavior is invoked, anything is possible. For example, a variable can be both true and false.
>   未定義動作が発動した場合、何でもありだ。例えば、変数は同時にtrueでもfalseでもありえる。

とのことです。

Comment: 動作未定義の変数が例えどんな値であっても質問での式の値は真になると思いますが、この場合の式の一部分の動作未定義が全体に波及する理由または根拠はなんですか？

Comment: リンク先の「しかし、もしそのような実行が未定義の操作を含む場合、この国際標準規格は実装に対し、そのような入力に対し、いかなる実行上の制約をも課すことはない（未定義操作に先行する操作をも含む）」の部分、規格でいうとどの章にあたりますか？

Comment: 追加された部分、Ｃの規格で言うと、3.4.3 p2 がだいたい同じですね。つまり、規格のそれは部分的なこと（のみ）について言っているのではなくて全体に波及して（全体の状況を無視する場合があると）解釈してよい。ということですね。よく言われる「何でもあり」については、強いて言えば、3.4.3 p１がそれに該当するということなんでしょう。

Comment: そういうわけではなく例えば`||`演算子は左辺値が真の場合に右辺値は評価してはいけないわけで、では左辺値が動作未定義の場合に右辺値を評価していいのか、というようにどうしても連鎖してしまうわけです。

Comment: それはつまり言い換えれば部分的に未定義動作部分があっても全体には波及しない場合があるということですか？例えば、`void func(void){int x; x==x;}`のようなまるで意味のない（つまり実質的な効果が何も無い）関数呼び出しの内部で未定義動作をしても連鎖することはない。ということですか？だとすると今までの話と異なると思いますが。

Comment: それこそリンク先の記事をご確認ください。。

Comment: あなたに訊いているんですけど。「そういうわけではなく」の部分（つまり私の解釈の違う点について）に関連することだと思いますけど。

Comment: なぜ未定義動作がどのような動作になるかを規定しようとするのでしょうか？ 引用したようにコンパイルに成功することすら保証されてなく、コンパイルエラーでも何でもありなのですが。

Comment: 私のコメント（解釈）（なんでもありだから）「部分のみならず全体の状況を‌​無視する場合がある」について「そういうわけではなく」と言ったのでは無いということですね。では何が違ったのでしょうか？

Comment: 回答の「..さんは...混同が多々見られます」の部分、[個人に対する批評](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)と取れますし、回答情報を求める読者にはノイズとなります。言語仕様と具体的実装の区別は有用と思いますので、質問内容に焦点をあてた形に書き直すのはいかがでしょうか。もしくは該当段落の削除をお願いできますでしょうか。

Comment: @ento さん、リンク先のコメント欄を参照してください。今までコメントで何度も指摘・議論を重ねていますが、BLUEPIXYさんの「仕様」と「実装」の違いに関する勘違いは一向に改善されません。個人批判ではなく、誤った理解の元で質問を繰り返していることを指摘しただけです。その上でこの問題をどう指摘するのが適切でしょうか？
 `s/BLUEPIXYさん/質問者さん/` とすれば問題ないでしょうか？

Comment: 投稿者の勘違い、のような証明が難しい事象より、誰もが確認できる投稿文面について議論するのが建設的ではないかと思います。「質問者さんは…」としてもやはり「人」を主題にしているので、それがもし今回最も役立つアプローチであるとしても、第三者にとって「スタックオーバーフローで質問すると自分に矛先が向けられるかも」のような印象になることをおそれます。

Comment: 実際どうするか：今回の質問文は規格に100%準じた理想世界の質問か、実装に関する現実世界の質問かが明示されていないので（`c`のタグのみ付いているので、前者という推測はできますけれど）、質問へのコメントで意図を確認するか、回答で「規格上は…だが、実際には実装次第」のような具体的な線引きを示す、でしょうか。理解を深めるには複数の具体例が役立つものと思いますし、リンクされているやり取りも、「同様に規格と実装の区別が不可欠になる例」という枠組みで、人物に焦点をあてることなく入れ込めるかと思います。

Comment: もっと緊密なやりとりをしないと認識が合わなそう、となったらチャットがよいかもしれないですね。あるいは自己Q&A形式で「Cコードの動作において規格はどういう役割を果たしているのか」についてより網羅的な回答を投稿するか。これらは「意図の確認→認識の同期」というパターンですが、もし「そこまでの時間はない・同じ点について説明するのは疲れる」という側面もあるようでしたら、一旦他の人に回答をまかせるのも戦略としてありかと思います。